# How can I create a new List<T> based on two other List<T> and account for duplicates?

Tags: c#, algorithm, sorting

My first post. Humbled by this community. Thank you.

**The goal:** Create a new `List<PropertyB>` based on two other lists:
 `List<PropertyA>` and another `List<PropertyB>`.

For each PropertyA in the `List<PropertyA>`, create a new `PropertyB()`, assigning the DisplayName to the new PropertyB's Name property. For each property in 'List', if the name from PropertyA matches PropertyB, assign the value to the new list's value property.

**The problem:** Accounting for Duplicate values. No data loss can occur between the lists.

**The new list should include:** Every PropertyA and every Value of the PropertyB list where there is a Name match.
The types:

**My thoughts:** My gut says the inner loop should check whether something has already been added to the collection. Or perhaps an accounting of duplicate values (ie: the index of duplicates?)

Any assistance is appreciated!

```
 public class PropertyA{
      private string DisplayName{get; set;}
      private string Name {get; set;}
      private string Value {get; set;}
}
```

```
 public class PropertyB{
      private string Name{get; set;}
      private string Value{get; set;}
}
```

Initialization:

```
List<PropertyA> listA = new List<PropertyA>()
{
      new PropertyA(){ DisplayName="LOB", Name="lineofbusiness", Value="test"},
      new PropertyA(){ DisplayName="ABC", Name="alpha", Value="test2"},
      new PropertyA(){ DisplayName="DEF", Name="beta", Value="test3"},
      new PropertyA(){ DisplayName="GHI", Name="zeta", Value="test4"},
      new PropertyA(){ DisplayName"Line of Business", Name="lineofbusiness", Value="test5"
};
List<PropertyB> listB = new List<PropertyB>()
{
      new PropertyB(){ Name="lineofbusiness", Value="test789"},
      new PropertyB(){ Name="alpha", Value="test234"},
      new PropertyB(){ Name="lineofbusiness", Value="test456"},
      new PropertyB(){ Name="beta", Value="test123"},
};
```

In Main:

```
List<PropertyB> newList = new List<PropertyB>();

foreach(PropertyA propA in listA){
      PropertyB newProp = new PropertyB();
      newProp.Name = propA.DisplayName;
     
     foreach(PropertyB propB in listB){
     
          if(propA.Name == propB.Name){
               newProp.Value = propB.Value;
               break; 
          }
     }
     newList.Add(newProp);
}
```

**UPDATE:**
The console output (if you choose) **should** be as follows:

```
LOB test789
ABC test234 
DEF test123 
GHI null 
Line of Business test456
```

if you simply remove the `break;` you end up with:

```
LOB test456
ABC test234 
DEF test123 
GHI null 
Line of Business test456
```

The inner loop will always assign the LAST name match value. That's a problem.

Comment: Can you show us expected output?

Comment: What is wrong with your code?

Comment: PropertyB has fewer properties than PropertyA. So I don't think there is data loss.

Comment: @wseipel Just remove break. What is the problem with it? I don't understand what to do with the second value? Are you going to make an array or what? Maybe a comma separated string as it offered  in the answer? This is why your question is unclear.

Comment: @Serge Let me clarify: The new list should contain EVERY DisplayName from List<PropertyA> (stored in 'Name') and every value from List<PropertyB> where the Name properites match.
Removing the 'break;' will not get the first VALUE where the Name=lineofbusiness. Removing the break guarantees it will always retain the SECOND instance where the name = lineofbusiness.

Comment: @wseipel I am sorry, but I don't think that anybody else understands what do you want. If you still need help then post the list what do you want to have in the end.

Comment: Please see my UPDATE in the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can just fix your code, add a check for duplicates

```
List<PropertyB> newList = new List<PropertyB>();

foreach(PropertyA propA in listA)
{

 PropertyB newProp = new PropertyB();
  newProp.Name = propA.DisplayName;

foreach (var propB in listB)
{
    if (propA.Name == propB.Name)
    {
        if( newList.Any(l =>l.Value==propB.Value )) continue;
        newProp.Value = propB.Value;
        break;
    }
}
 newList.Add(newProp);
}
```

but to make it more reliable I would offer this

```
    List<PropertyA> newList = new List<PropertyA>();

    foreach (var propA in listA)
    {
        var newProp = new PropertyA();
        newProp.Name = propA.DisplayName;
        
        newProp.DisplayName = propA.Name;
        
        foreach (var propB in listB)
        {
            if (propA.Name == propB.Name)
            {
            if (newList.Any(l => l.Value == propB.Value 
                           && l.DisplayName==propA.Name)) continue;
                newProp.Value = propB.Value;
                break;
            }
        }
    
        newList.Add(newProp);
    }

    var result = newList.Select(l => new PropertyB {Name=l.Name, Value=l.Value} );
```

both algorithms show the same result during the test

```
LOB test789
ABC test234 
DEF test123 
GHI null 
Line of Business test456
```

Comment: Explain what you "fixed" so the OP can learn something.

Comment: Removing the 'break' doesn't fix it. Quite the opposite. And the property can't be changed to an array.

Comment: @wseipel Ok, I changed my code. Now result is the same as you want

Comment: Outstanding! Interesting how you swapped PropertyB for PropertyA in the first loop. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I understood the process:

1. list of A needs turning into a list of B
2. Some of the list of B items might have a Value copied from some other list of B

```
    var d = bList.ToDictionary(b => b.Name, b => b.Value);
    var newB = aList.Select(a => new B { Name = a.DisplayName, Value = d.GetValueOrDefault(a.Name) } ).ToList();
```

You said no data shall be lost but I think inherently you must have to throw something away because B has fewer properties than A and some properties from B are used to "overwrite"/take the place of those in A..

I note also you have duplicated Name in your sample data list B, which the ToDictionary won't tolerate. You didn't specify how to resolve this but you'll have to choose (if it truly does occur) what value to pick or if to take multiple. This, for example, would tolerate duplicate names

```
    var d = bList.ToLookup(b => b.Name, b => b.Value);
    var newB = aList.Select(a => new B { Name = a.DisplayName, Value = d[a.Name]?.First() } ).ToList();
```

Again, this throws stuff away.. if you want to keep all the values you'll have to encode the Value somehow

```
Value = string.Join(",", d[a.Name])
```

for example

---

So, it looks like you want to keep all the duplicates and dispense them in order. We could do that by grouping these things into a list that we pull the items out of as we enumerate

```
    var d = bList.GroupBy(b => b.Name, b => b.Value).ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.ToList());
   
    var newB = new List<B>();
    foreach(var a in aList){
      var b = new B { Name = a.DisplayName };

      if(d.TryGetValue(a.Name, out var lst)){
        b.Value = lst[0];
        lst.RemoveAt(0);
      }
    }
```

Comment: The output should be as follows:

`

LOB test789
ABC test234
DEF test123
GHI null
Line of Business test123

Comment: Wanted to clarify: 
At minimum, the new List<PropertyB> should have every Name = List<PropertyA>.DisplayName. 
So, if the LIst<PropertyA> has 20 items, there should be 20 items in the new LIst<PropertyB>.
If there is no Name match, the value of the new PropertyB should be null.

Comment: The duplicate 'lineofbusiness' is the problem. How to create a new PropertyB WITH that value...as well as the first one.

Comment: And that's the part you need to clarify. Which lineofbusiness do you want? And if you want both (or some, or all of there are 3+ then which and..), how do you want them?

Comment: I've posted an update of what the sample output would look like. 
I need both: The new list should have 5 PropertyB's in it. One of those will have the Name = LOB and a value of test789 and the other should have the Name = Line of Business and a value of test456.

Comment: So you want to dole out the lineofbusiness records in the order they appear in each list?